# Gui for GRUB4DOS

Tags: command-line, grub, grub4dos

is there Gui for grub4dos i think if this found will help all people to make bootable cd without to learn or know or write any code or line

so is there any Gui for it?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! It seems there are plenty of GRUB4DOS guides online (e.g. [this one](http://diddy.boot-land.net/grub4dos/Grub4dos.htm)) … do you have any *specific* problem you're currently facing?

Comment: no thanks man i wanna to learn it to make my bootable cd as i said and put it all program run under dos and other so thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Diddy-Boot-Land](http://diddy.boot-land.net) has a few that you might like (as [@slhck](https://superuser.com/users/48078/slhck) pointed out): [1](http://diddy.boot-land.net/grub4dos/files/commands.htm); [2](http://diddy.boot-land.net/grub4dos/files/map.htm); [3](http://diddy.boot-land.net/grub4dos/files/cli.htm) in English

Google is your friend on this one as well, asking specific questions in google will give you some good results.

I couldn't find any Arabic documentation, but even if I did I wouldn't know if it's helpful. Perhaps try [Google Arabic](http://www.google.ae/)

## Edit

also be sure to read the **README file** that comes with [the program](http://sourceforge.net/projects/grub4dos/files/GRUB4DOS/)

Comment: thank you very much man for you help you help me so much i will try with link above thank i wanna vote you up i can't because my reputation still low thank you and for slhck